# python xpath space not getting removed

Tags: python, xpath

i am trying to get some data from a html page that has tables in it. i got a list of rows ugin xpath and now i am trying to get text() inside each element of `td` inside `tr`, here is the basic structure of `tr`

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" onclick="WhoisOrderDomain('bank'); return false;"> SHOP
                        </a>
  </td>
  <td>COUNTRY</td>
  <td class="text-right">1 038,00 USD</td>
  <td class="text-right">899,00 USD</td>
  <td class="text-right">899,00 USD</td>
  <td class="text-center">
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="#" onclick="WhoisOrderDomain('bank'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Order</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

below is my xpath in python:

```
td_xpath = XPath("./td/a/text()[normalize-space()] | ./td/text()[normalize-space()]")
```

and i am getting this output:

```
['\r\n                          SHOP\r\n                        ', 'COUNTRY', '1038,00 USD', '899,00 USD', '899,00 USD', ' Order']
```

why spaces are not removed from first element?

also how to use xpath to remove ',' and 'USD' from prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[td.xpath('normalize-space()')for td in tree.xpath('//tr/td')]
```

out:

```
['SHOP', 'COUNTRY', '1 038,00 USD', '899,00 USD', '899,00 USD', 'Order']
```

`[normalize-space()]` is a filter that get rid of the empty string. if you need to get the string under a tag, use `normalize-space(tag)`

use `strip` or `replace` to get rid of `USD`

```
[td.xpath('normalize-space()').strip(' USD') for td in tree.xpath('//tr/td')]
```

out:

```
['HOP', 'COUNTRY', '1 038,00', '899,00', '899,00', 'Order']
```

EDIT:

```
tree.xpath('//tr/td//text()')
```

out:

```
['\n    ',                           # empty, discard
 ' SHOP\n                        ',
 '\n  ',                             # empty, discard
 'COUNTRY',
 '1 038,00 USD',
 '899,00 USD',
 '899,00 USD',
 '\n',                               # empty, discard
 ' Order',
 '\n                      ']         # empty, discard
```

If `[normalize-space()]` affect string, you output `' Order'` will not contains the whitespace at the begaining.

`[]` will only act like boolean value to filter false value, it will not change the value.

Comment: @anekix [normalize-space()] is a filter that get rid of the empty string. it will not change the string.

Comment: Thankyou for your response but i am having difficuly understanding why my code was not working? `./td/a/text()[normalize-space()]` this seleects /td/a/text() then applies filter to it right? because the next xpath with same syntax is working

Comment: how can i remove ',' and USD from currency?

Comment: @anekix `[td.xpath('normalize-space()').strip(' USD').replace(',', '') for td in tree.xpath('//tr/td')]`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is properly normalize the value:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1 038,00 USD'.rstrip('USD').replace(' ','').replace(',','.'))
Decimal('1038.00')
```

Always use `Decimal` for monetary values. This avoids the issues of numerical inaccuracy that plague floats and can cost you cents.

---

To process the list you filter out those strings that are not monetary values in this case those that do not end in `USD` (there might be another way that fits your XML input better) and then convert the rest:

```
input_values = ['.ac.tz', 'Tanzania', '135,00 USD', '135,00 USD', '0,00 USD', ' Order']
monetary_values = [Decimal(v.rstrip('USD').replace(' ','').replace(',','.')) 
                   for v in input_values if v.endswith('USD')]
```

Results in:

```
>>> monetary_values
[Decimal('135.00'), Decimal('135.00'), Decimal('0.00')]
```

Or you could attempt to convert every item and ignore those that raise an exception:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

input_values = ['.ac.tz', 'Tanzania', '135,00 USD', '135,00 USD', '0,00 USD', ' Order']

monetary_values = [] 
for v in input_values:
    try:
        monetary_values.append(Decimal(v.rstrip('USD').replace(' ','').replace(',','.')))
    except decimal.InvalidOperation:
        pass
```

Which also results in:

```
>>> monetary_values
[Decimal('135.00'), Decimal('135.00'), Decimal('0.00')]
```

Comment: but why the space is not being normalized in my xpath? i want the result using xpath

Comment: i ahve a list like this ['.ac.tz', 'Tanzania', '135,00 USD', '135,00 USD', '0,00 USD', ' Order']
 how do i aplly this to it?